Movie about a woman and a man that meet in a dream
This movie is about a guy and a woman. The guy works (probably) in a coffee shop. When he went to sleep he dreamed about this woman who's in a coma and in this coma she dreamed about him. They met in this dream. One day she woke up and met this guy in real life (i think in the coffee shop). They talked about going on a date but when she was leaving the coffee shop she was hit by a truck/car and she died there on the spot. After that he went to a fortune teller who gave him a locket that he put above his bed to dream about the woman that died. So anyone? 
Can anyone help me?

When did this movie come out? Theatrical/made-for-tv/video? Country of origin?

I think you're looking for Awaken (2012).

Alex's dreary life is reignited when he meets Rachel, the woman of his dreams. The only thing that stands in the way of their perfect, serendipitous relationship is that Rachel has recently passed away.

Alex owns a coffee shop, and after Rachel dies in a car accident, he keeps seeing her in his dreams as a psychic woman gives him a dreamcatcher to hang over his bed. Here's the trailer:




Sounds right. Embellished a bit & +1.
